# How to turn-on the module 'auto_explain'?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to turn on the module ['auto_explain'](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/auto-explain.html) in the PostgreSQL. I use Docker 'postgres' image which is "psql (PostgreSQL) 12.1 (Debian 12.1-1.pgdg100+1)" version. So, I do:

```sql
postgres=# load 'auto_explain';
LOAD
postgres=# set auto_explain.log_min_duration=0;
SET
postgres=# set auto_explain.log_verbose=true;
SET
postgres=# select count(*) from city;
 count 
-------
  4079
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

and nothing. No any logs, but as I understood, it should print logs on the console of my psql session. I tried to look for some .log files from PostgreSQL: `/var/log/postgresql/` is empty. What am I missing from sight? Some additional option?

EDIT:

Also I tried to add `-L file.log` option to the psql, but the resulting log file looks like:

```
********* QUERY **********
load 'auto_explain';
**************************

LOAD
********* QUERY **********
set auto_explain.log_verbose=true;
**************************

SET
********* QUERY **********
set auto_explain.log_min_duration=0;
**************************

SET
********* QUERY **********
select count(*) from city;
**************************

 count 
-------
  4079
(1 row)
```

so no any plans there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The messages will be written to the log file at the level `LOG`.

If you want to see them in your client session as well, you must set `client_min_messages` to `log`.